# Swift: could not cast value of type 'UIImageView' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have done this code below, i want to detect when the player touches the left and right side of the screen, to do it i have put two images on the right side and the left side, so was caught a thread. I do not know how to resolve it, does anyone do?

```
@IBOutlet weak var player: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rightSide: UIDynamicItem!
@IBOutlet weak var leftSide: UIDynamicItem!

var detectRightCollision: UICollisionBehavior!
var detectLeftCollision: UICollisionBehavior!

func checkEdgesTouched() -> Bool{

   detectRightCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: rightSide as! [UIDynamicItem])
    detectLeftCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: leftSide as! [UIDynamicItem])

    if detectLeftCollision == true {
        Setscore()
        return true
    } else if detectRightCollision == true {
        Setscore()
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Your explanation does not make much sense. Post the actual code that is generating the error and tell us the specific line number that causes that error.

Comment: The code that is generating the error is: detectRightCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: rightSide as! [UIDynamicItem])

Comment: @flashspys gave you the correct answer. (voted.) You should accept it, and fix your code as he describes.

Comment: yeah, i have already did it

Comment: Then accept his answer. If you don't accept people's answers when they answer your question it's bad form and people will start ignoring your questions.

Comment: oh, i didn't know it. Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast an element to an array. What you want is to init an array with only one element:

```
detectRightCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [rightSide])
```